# Django Rest Framework: How to implement a nested logic?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Let's say I have three models as:

```
class User(AppModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Business(AppModel):
    owner = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="businesses", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Invoice(AppModel):
    business = models.ForeignKey("Business", related_name="invoices", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.integerField()
```

As you can see, a `user` can have multiple `businesses` and a `business` can have multiple `invoices`.

My serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ('name')

class BusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields= ('owner','legal_name')

class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    business= BusinessSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields= ('business','amount')
```

views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class BusinessViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Business.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BusinessSerializer

class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('user', UserViewSet, base_name='users')
router.register('business', BusinessViewSet, base_name='businesses')
router.register('invoice', InvoiceViewSet, base_name='invoices')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

`http://example.com/api/user` returns all users. Not a problem.

But the functionality I'm looking for is:

- `http://example.com/api/business/` returns

  `[
  {
      "legal_name": "1business",
      "owner": 1,
  },
  {
      "legal_name": "2business",
      "owner": 1,
  },]`
- `http://example.com/api/business/1/` returns

  `{
  "legal_name": "1business",
  "owner": 1,
  }`

The above is ok. But I also need:

- `http://example.com/api/business/1/invoices/` should return

  `[
  {
      "business": 1,
      "amount": 100,
  },
  {
      "business": 1,
      "amount": 999,
  },]`

As well I should be able to create update delete those invoices there.

Any Help? I'm new to django rest framework. The above classes are just a sample. Ignore errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should use django decorators which are `@list_route` and `@detail_route` for your viewset. But be careful with your DRF version. Because those decorators merged together as `@action` in DRF 3.8+. Here is the [announcement](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.8-announcement/#deprecations).

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class BusinessViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Business.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BusinessSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=["GET"], url_path="invoices")
    def invoices(self, request, pk=None):
        """
         Your codes comes here to return related result.
         pk variable contains the param value from url.
         if you do not specify the url_path properties then action will accept the function's name as url path.
        """
        entity = Invoice.objects.filter(business=pk)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(entity, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Then, you will be able to call this endpoints from;

```
http://example.com/api/business/{{PK}}/invoices/
http://example.com/api/business/1/invoices/
http://example.com/api/business/3/invoices/
http://example.com/api/business/23/invoices/
```

Here you can find more details about `@actions` from [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing).

PS: Don't forget to control empty entity results in your codes. You should return correct response with correct status codes.